# How to verify two Images using Azure Cognitive Face API in JavaScript

Tags: java, azure

I'm trying to use Microsoft Azure Face API in Javascript to verify two faces. I follow their sample codes and found one javascript API. In the below sample code how can I pass the two images that I want to verify in the body section of this API? Can someone give me an example pls?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script 
     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"> 
     </script>
     </head>
    <body>

     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
            var params = {
        // Request parameters
       };
  
        $.ajax({
         url: 
             "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/verify?" 
              + $.param(params),
               beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"," 
            {subscription key}");
         },
         type: "POST",
         // Request body
         data: "{body}",
           })
       .done(function(data) {
        alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
          });
      });
      </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Below sample works for me.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            faceapi();
        })
        
        function faceapi(){
            var SendInfo= { faceId: '43a4de00-e750-4bb8-8379-de3b33c9c0a6',personId:'2c0f2289-68cc-4cf6-ab12-9c0eec6bf3c7',largePersonGroupId:'112233'};
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://yoursourcename.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/verify',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(SendInfo),
                beforeSend: function(request) {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json');
                    request.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", 'yourkey');

                },
                success: function(res){
                    console.log(res)
                }
            });
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use our face verification api which is available for free in [rapidapi](https://rapidapi.com/PresentID/api/face-verification2)